# Boxplot by two groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have the following dataset:

```
df_plots = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                         'Type':['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y'],
                         'Value':[1,1.2,1.4,1.3,1.8,1.5,15,19,18,17,12,13]})
df_plots
    Group   Type    Value
0   A       X       1.0
1   A       X       1.2
2   A       X       1.4
3   A       Y       1.3
4   A       Y       1.8
5   A       Y       1.5
6   B       X       15.0
7   B       X       19.0
8   B       X       18.0
9   B       Y       17.0
10  B       Y       12.0
11  B       Y       13.0
```

And I want to create boxplots per `Group` (there are two in the example) and in each plot to show by type. I have tried this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, g in enumerate(df_plots[['Group','Type','Value']].groupby(['Group','Type'])):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i])
```

- Results in an `IndexError`, because the loop tries to create 4 plots.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-8e1150950024> in <module>
      3 
      4 for i, g in enumerate(df[['Group','Type','Value']].groupby(['Group','Type'])):
----> 5     g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i])

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Then I tried this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,6), sharey=False)
axs = axs.flatten()

for i, g in enumerate(df_plots[['Group','Type','Value']].groupby(['Group','Type'])):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i], by=['Group','Type'])
```

But no, I have the same problem. The expected result should have only two plots, and each plot have a box-and-whisker per Type. This is a sketch of this idea:

[image]

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated, with this code I can control some aspects of the data that I can't with seaborn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Prune mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68734590/13138364), the immediate issue is that your `groupby()` returns four groups (AX, AY, BX, BY), so first fix the indexing and then clean up a couple more issues:

1. Change `axs[i]` to `axs[i//2]` to put groups 0 and 1 on `axs[0]` and groups 2 and 3 on `axs[1]`.
2. Add `positions=[i]` to place the boxplots side by side rather than stacked.
3. Set the `title` and `xticklabels` after plotting (I'm not aware of how to do this in the main loop).

```py
for i, g in enumerate(df_plots.groupby(['Group', 'Type'])):
    g[1].boxplot(ax=axs[i//2], positions=[i])

for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.set_title('Group: ' + df_plots['Group'].unique()[i])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['Type: X', 'Type: Y'])
```

[image: boxplot output]

---

Note that mileage may vary depending on version:

|  | `matplotlib.__version__` | `pd.__version__` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| confirmed working | 3.4.2 | 1.3.1 |
| confirmed **not** working | 3.0.1 | 1.2.4 |

Comment: Hello @tdy, I tried your solution but I looks different from your image (mine only shows 1 boxplot per side). I even copy-pasted your code but I doesn't show what you have. Am I missing something?

Comment: hmm not sure. i just added a full minimal example that gives me your expected output. if that still doesn't give you the same result, maybe it's a version issue? I'm using matplotlib 3.4.2 and pandas 1.3.1

Comment: That must be the problem!, my matplotlib version is 3.0.1, and pandas version is 1.2.4, I'll try to update and see if I can reproduce your plot. Thank you!

Comment: That was the problem, the version! Now it's solved with your code, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

We can use [`groupby boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.boxplot.html) to create subplots per `Group` and then separate each `boxplot` by `Type`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 6), sharey=False)
df_plots.groupby('Group').boxplot(by='Type', ax=axes)
plt.show()
```

Or without `subplots` by passing parameters directly through the function call:

```
axes = df_plots.groupby('Group').boxplot(by='Type', figsize=(8, 6),
                                         layout=(1, 2), sharey=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

Data and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df_plots = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Type': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
    'Value': [1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.8, 1.5, 15, 19, 18, 17, 12, 13]
})
```

Comment: I was surprised that `by='Type'` doesn't seem to work correctly with `df_plots.groupby('Group').plot(kind='box', by='Type', figsize=(8, 6), layout=(1, 2), sharey=False)`

Comment: It seems in my quick (and by no means comprehensive read through of some of the source code) that the `by` gets passed to `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot` which doesn't handle the `by`, while `groupby.boxplot` passes to `DataFrame.boxplot` which _does_ handle the `by` and passes the remaining values to `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(data=df, kind='box', col='Group', x='Type', y='Value', hue='Type', sharey=False, height=4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @mozway, I appreciate your answer but I would prefer it with the given code, without seaborn, because I have to make some calculations inside the loop. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Can't you use [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) then? It can take care of the figure layout and still give you access to the raw data per group. If you really don't want to, preprocess your data and group only by 'Group' to plot.

Comment: @Alexis _I have to make some calculations inside the loop_ is not shown in the OP. It is better to separate calculation steps from plotting steps.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that your `groupby` operation returns four elements (AX, AY, BX, BY), which you're trying to plot individually.  You try to use `ax=axs[i]` ... but `i` runs 0-3, while you have only the two elements in your flattened structure.  There is no `axs[2]` or `axs[3]`, which raises the given run-time exception.

You need to resolve your referencing one way or the other.